# Marshalling complex structs to C#

Tags: c#, struct, marshalling

I have a complex struct and I want to marshall it to use it in C#. 
I got the "FILE" struct to use as example

```
#pragma pack(4)
typedef struct  __file__{
        short           token;          /* Used for validity checking */
        unsigned short  flags;          /* File status flags          */
        unsigned char   hold;           /* Ungetc char if no buffer   */
        int             fd;             /* File descriptor            */
        int             level;          /* fill/empty level of buffer */
        int             bsize;          /* Buffer size                */
        unsigned char   *buffer;        /* Data transfer buffer       */
        unsigned char   *curp;          /* Current active pointer     */
        struct __file2{
            char *name;                 /* filename */
            enum { 
                __or_unspecified,
                __or_narrow, 
                __or_wide 
            } orient;                   /* stream orientation */
            int mbstate[2];             /* space for mbstate_t structure */
        } *extended;
}       FILE;                           /* This is the FILE object    */
#pragma pack()
```

So, how I can convert this struct to C# ?

My actual conversion is this:

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, Pack = 4)]
struct FILE
{
    public short token;
    public ushort flags;
    public byte hold;
    public int fd;
    public int level;
    public int bsize;
    public UIntPtr buffer;
    public UIntPtr curp;

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    public struct extended
    {
        public char[] name;
        public enum orient
        {
            __or_unspecified,
            __or_narrow,
            __or_wide
        }
        [MarshalAsAttribute(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 2)]
        public int[] mbstate;
    }
}
```

In the C struct, the struct __file2 is a pointer, "*extended;", how this can be converted ?

Comment: in C# you can define your class/function as `unsafe`. Then you can use the `*` operator to indicate a pointer

Comment: That's not possible, you can only declare a pointer to a blittable type, `__file2` is not because of the string.  C pointers in general are ambiguous, could be a pointer to a *single* struct, could be a pointer to the first element of an array of structs.  In this specific case it is not an array.  Something you have to know to do it correctly.  Since it is not blittable, declaring `__file2` as a class is not useful either.  And you have to fall back to IntPtr and marshal yourself.  Posting a declaration that doesn't have anything to do with your code is a big waste of time btw.

Comment: For something like that, you would probably need to write your own code... And by the way, if you do a C# structure, you probably want to use C# friendly types like `string`.

Comment: The function return to me, a struct pointer, to a struct like that..., so, one possibility is, put to outside of struct FILE, the struct extended and create a IntPtr to this struct....